# react native textinput goes out of my view

Tags: react-native, expo

why my text input goes out of my view ?

```
const Search = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParams>>();

  const handleGoBack = () => navigation.goBack();
  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor='#fff' />
      <View style={s.header}>
        <GoBackIcon
          onPress={handleGoBack}
          color='#333'
        />
        <Input style={s.input} icon={<Ionicons name="ios-search-outline" size={24} color="black" />} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight + 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 7,
  },
  input: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    alignContent: 'stretch',
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
  }
})

export default Search
```

Here is an image:

[image]

i am very thankful for your help......................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the style of input is flexGow, it will take over the vertical space as much as it can. You can set the header width to deminsion width to avoid this issue.

```js
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
```

```js
    header: {
    width:Dimensions.get("window").width;,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight + 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 7,
  },
```